# How to translate PDF file?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a PDF file with tables, images and so on. I want to translate text of this PDF file into another language and create a PDF file that is similar to the first file but contains translated text (it should have images, tables, ... like first file).

How can I write a program in C++ that does this work?

I have a program that extracts text from PDF file and converts text but I can't create output PDF file with tables and images in special positions. How can I create a PDF file that has the layout as the original file?

Answer (score 0):

Your program should read the PDF in a memory structure (like a tree of objects) then translate the text leafs in memory, then dump the memory structure back to PDF.
To do so, you need a pdf parsing library which allows you to manipulate the object representation.

I am not a C++ dev, so I don't know the C++ library universe; but from a quick search on google, it looks like [PoDoFo](http://podofo.sourceforge.net/about.html) can do this job.